# Propagate a value in child components

Tags: polymer-3.x, lit-element

A button toggles a boolean value in `MainComp`.
**I want to propagate the value in both the nested child components**. My real project works with the first level child, it fails to update the second level child component.
But oddly enough trying to replicate the code in codepen I noticed it doesn't work for the first level child either.

https://codepen.io/alfredopacino/pen/eqVGJa?editors=1001

```
class MainComp extends LitElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.booleanValue = true
    }
    toggleBooleanValue() {
        this.booleanValue = !this.booleanValue
        this.requestUpdate();
    }
    render() {
        return html `
<style>  div {padding: 1em; border:1px solid #000} </style>
<div> main component booleanValue: ${!!this.booleanValue} <button @click=${this.toggleBooleanValue}>toggle</button>
 <child-comp ?booleanValue=${this.booleanValue}></child-comp>
</div>
`
    }
}

class ChildComp extends LitElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
    static get properties() {
        return {
            booleanValue: Boolean
        }
    }
    render() {
        return html `
<style>  div {padding: 1em; border:1px solid green} </style>
<div> child component booleanValue: ${!!this.booleanValue}
<child-2-comp ?booleanValue=${this.booleanValue}></child-2-comp>
</div>
   `
    }
}

class Child_2_Comp extends LitElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
    static get properties() {
        return {
            booleanValue: Boolean
        }
    }
    render() {
        return html `
<style>  div {padding: 1em; border:1px solid red} </style>
<div> child 2 component booleanValue: ${!!this.booleanValue}</div>
   `
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `booleanValue` in MainComp to trigger a render you must either add it to MainComp's properties:

```
class MainComp extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      booleanValue: {type: Boolean}
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the property is defined as `{type: Boolean}` and not just `Boolean` this is required for LitElement to know how to treat the property when doing the update

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/luwuregebu/edit?html,output)

For more info check these two guides from the LitElement docs
https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/properties
https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/lifecycle

Comment: I don't get why I need to declare that property in `MainComp`..unless properties are to be intended more like instance variables than component props (in React way)

Comment: Properties in litelement are somewhat both things at the same time, you could actually do this without using them but in that case you would need to call `this.requestUpdate()` every time you updated your property manually

Comment: So in general it's easier to just add them as properties in the getter, even if you set attribute to false so that they aren't modifiable from there